# Cannot center tikz picture in tabular environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\addvmargin[1]{%
  \node[fit=(current bounding box),inner ysep=#1,inner xsep=0]{};
}
\newcommand{\mysymbol}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
        \tikz \draw (2,0) node{#1} circle (2);
        \addvmargin{1mm}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline Symbol 1 & Symbol 2 \\\hline
\mysymbol{foo} & \mysymbol{bar} \\\hline
\mysymbol{baz} & \mysymbol{foobar} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the distance from the tikz picture to the vertical table border lines is slightly shorter than the right one. The picture is therefore not fully centered, but need to be moved a little bit to the right.

Do you have any idea why it isn't centered, and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Try adding `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}`. A line break is a space.

Comment: @cfr that was my problem, thank you! Could you please create an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A line break is a space. Putting a `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\addvmargin[1]{%
  \node[fit=(current bounding box),inner ysep=#1,inner xsep=0]{};
}
\newcommand{\mysymbol}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
        \tikz \draw (2,0) node{#1} circle (2);
        \addvmargin{1mm}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline Symbol 1 & Symbol 2 \\\hline
\mysymbol{foo} & \mysymbol{bar} \\\hline
\mysymbol{baz} & \mysymbol{foobar} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: centred circles]